# Unable to install TestNG in eclipse using eclipse Market place or Install software

Tags: testng

I'm unable to install TestNG in my eclipse.

1. I tried from eclipse marketplace which gave the following error:
   "The following solutions are not available: TestNG for eclipse
   Proceed with the installation?" Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJ7OR.png , with Yes or No buttons if i click yes, it gives: "Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details."
2. When I tried through Install New Software options, it doesn't display testNG icon in the list as it supposed to..

Is there any solution for this or any alternate way to install?

Comment: Have you tried installing from testng.org? BTW, you really, really need to indicate what version of Eclipse you are using and what version of TestNG you are trying to install. Without that we are just guessing.

Comment: I'm using eclipse 4.2.0 and I'm trying to install latest version of TestNG i.e. TestNG 6.8.6 and i'm using this link: http://beust.com/eclipse to get TestNG.

Comment: I couldn't find 4.2.0, but installed 4.2.2 of Eclipse. I then used the link you just provided in the Install New Software ... dialog. After accepting an unsigned module, it installed fine. I suspect you may need to update your Eclipse to a later revision on the 4.2.x line.

Comment: Bob, I appreciate your help. I found a solution for my problem. Actually i could able to install TestNG in home but was failed in office with the same package. I doubt it was the problem with my office network. Might be firewall stopping it to download TestNG but i'm not sure. Now i downloaded the latest Eclipse Kepler version and installed TestNG in home, copied it and put in my office PC. Its working perfectly :-).. I mean fully configured at home and transferred to office PC.

Comment: Another note: depending when and how you did your installs, it is possible that your installation is corrupted or your workspace is corrupted. From your description, I believe it may have been the latter.

Comment: Yes that's another point too..

Comment: I tried doing the same with Eclipse 2019R06, Eclipse 2018-12, Oxygen etc versions, and all of them had the same problem, when at work. But my computer did not complain and installed perfectly. So, it is a proxy preventing it. When I disabled it, it is working perfectly. To figure this out, I need to waste so many hours. But it is my bad that, it has been mentioned in the troubleshooting guide though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

was facing same issue as i was unable to install same from market and install option. Finally it helped me to sole the issue by following 3rd method listed in below link.

https://www.techbeamers.com/install-testng-in-eclipse-ide/#method3

Install TestNG In Eclipse IDE Via Offline Jar Files.

First step:

Firstly download the latest TestNG Jar files from the link given below. We’ve provided the direct URL to download the TestNG version 6.11.

Clicking on the link will download the “site_assembly.zip” file for the TestNG version 6.11. This file contains two folders named as “features” and “plugins“.

The features folder contains the following two files.

org.testng.eclipse.maven.feature_6.11.0.201703011520.jar org.testng.eclipse_6.11.0.201703011520.jar The plugins folder contains these two files.

org.testng.eclipse.maven_6.11.0.201703011520.jar org.testng.eclipse_6.11.0.201703011520.jar Note – You can check for more recent releases of TestNG

Second step:

Go to the eclipse installation directory and look for the “dropins” folder there.
Create a folder inside the dropins folder and name it as “testng-eclipse-6.11“.
6->Major version & 11->Minor version of the TestNG plugin.

Extract the “site_assembly.zip” file and copy its content i.e. the “features” and “plugins” folders to the newly created “testng-eclipse-6.11” directory.
The eclipse install directory would now look like this or similar to this.

C:\Users\techbeamers\eclipse jee-neon\ dropins\ testng-eclipse-6.11\ features\ org.testng.eclipse.maven.feature_6.11.0.201703011520.jar org.testng.eclipse_6.11.0.201703011520.jar plugins\ org.testng.eclipse.maven_6.11.0.201703011520.jar org.testng.eclipse_6.11.0.201703011520.jar

Note – We’ve tested this option with the Eclipse Neon/juno version.

Third step:

Last but not the least, you will need to restart or start the Eclipse to see the TestNG plugin getting loaded into the IDE. However, the process would be slightly slow as the Eclipse will first time load the new plugin.

From Eclipse, by pressing CTRL+N, you can open the “New” wizard. It will load the list of all available module/project templates. By scrolling down in the list, you can make sure that it has the “TestNG” option.

Comment: This did not work for eclipse 2019-6 version and testNG 6.14.3 version

Comment: Worked for 2020-03

Answer (score 9):

The new link for install softwares has been updated recently.

Refer : https://testng.org/doc/download.html

New steps:
Goto Help->Install New Software

Type http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/. in "Work with" field and Click Add

Once you click on "Add", it will display the screen, enter the Name as "TestNG".

After clicking on "OK", it will scan and display TestNG with 3 files

Now select TestNG and next next and follow eclipse steps

Comment: This was asked 6 years back. Anyway it would help anyone looking for an answer now. Up-voted.

Comment: A new way to install TestNG on Eclipse, it works well

Comment: Tanks! Esto funcionó para mi.

Comment: I was following a website tutorial and got stuck, after reading this I was able to add TestNG. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**- Download the latest eclipse from below currently it is 2020-03**

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

**- To install TestNG**

1. Click "Help -> Install New Software..." on top level menu
2. Paste the url (Check the source below for latest supporting URL)

https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site

to Work with: text field and press enter.

3. Select the plugins
4. Click "Next" button and accept the license to complete the
   installation.
5. Restart Eclipse

Source:

https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse#install-snapshot

**- To install cucumber**

1. Type in name “Cucumber”
2. Type “http://cucumber.github.com/cucumber-eclipse/update-site” as
   location.
3. Click OK.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the source, as this keep on on updating with new location,
this is working now, https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site

Answer (score 2):

Follow below steps:

1. Install TestNG zip folder from below location
   https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/zipped/7.4.0.202106051955/org.testng.eclipse.updatesite.zip
2. GoTo Help ==> Install New Software
3. Click on Add Button
4. Enter Name and Add Downloaded zip folder location in Location text box
5. Click on Add Button
6. It will scan and display TestNG
7. Now select TestNG and next and default things.

Comment: Note that with a concrete version number this answer is bound to be outdated sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 1):

Those who are using some of the latest version of Eclipse like  2019.06 which I am using, will face issue in downloading TestNG through Eclipse MarketPlace.

WorkAround:

- Goto Help->Install New Software
- Type http://beust.com/eclipse/ in Work with field and Click Add
- Once you click on "Add", it will display the screen, enter the Name as "TestNG".
- After clicking on "OK", it will scan and display TestNG
- Now select TestNG and next next and default things.

TestNG will get installed.

Answer (score 1):

Use site - "https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/" instead of  http://beust.com/eclipse/.
I have also added below configuration in eclipse configuration file.
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the latest link , please share and help others, i spent 2 days facing this stupid issue

go to help > install software > put this link in " work with :" and add
proceed next

https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/